# Error with big dimension using animate package

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

My error is with the  "Dimension too large" when I compile  the next code, Im trying to make an animation with function sin and cos. The error is in line

```
\draw[line width=1.pt,smooth,samples=50,domain=0.001:\theangle,blue] plot(\x+3.14,{sin(((\x))*180/pi)});
```

---

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}

\usecolortheme{whale}

\newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{0}
%
\begin{document}
%
%
%
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Sine and Cosine functions}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first]{30}
%
\whiledo{\theangle<359}{
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Axis
    \draw[thick,->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
    \draw[cyan,thick] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \node[red,below] at (1.2,0) {1};
    \node[red,above] at (0.4,-1.5) {-1};
    % 
    %Axis auxiliar
    \draw[thick,->] (3.14,0)--(10,0) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->] (3.14,-1.5)--(3.14,1.5) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
      %
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:1cm); % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,0) -- (\theangle:1cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
    %
    \draw[densely dotted,blue] (\theangle:1cm) -- (\theangle:1cm |- 0,0); % vertical line
    \draw[densely dotted,red] (\theangle:1cm) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:1cm); % horizontal line
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,->,rotate=\theangle] (0,0) -- (1,0); 
    % grid
    \draw [dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=1.57cm,ystep=1.0cm] (3.14,-1.5) grid (9.29,1.5);
    % funciones sen y cos
   \draw[line width=1.pt,smooth,samples=50,domain=0.001:\theangle,blue] plot(\x+3.14,{sin(((\x))*180/pi)});    
   \draw[line width=1.pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=0.0:\theangle,red] plot(\x+3.14,{cos(((\x))*180/pi)});     
    \node[red,blue,right] at (-2,-3.8) 
            {\footnotesize$\cos(\,\theangle^{\mathrm{o}}\,) = \pgfmathcos{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \node[red,red,right] at (-2,-3.4) 
            {\footnotesize$\sin(\,\theangle^{\mathrm{o}}\,) = \pgfmathsin{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \stepcounter{angle}
    \ifthenelse{\theangle<359}{
            \newframe
    }{
            \end{animateinline}
    }
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%
%
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm afraid you've encountered a famous and difficult to solve bug in PGF...

Answer (score 1):

Then let's use the `expl3` floating point unit instead, in particular its `fp_eval:n{...}` function.

Also, the `\multiframe` command should be used to build the loop around the parameterized `tikzpicture`, which is to be preferred over the `\whiledo` solution.

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usepackage{animate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\fpeval\fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Sine and Cosine functions}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{30}
  \multiframe{361}{iAngle=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Axis
    \draw[thick,->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0) node[below]{$x$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \node[red,below] at (1.2,0) {1};
    \node[red,above] at (0.4,-1.5) {-1};
    % 
    %Axis auxiliar
    \draw[thick,->] (2.0,0)--(9,0) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->] (2.0,-1.5)--(2.0,1.5) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
      %
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \iAngle:1cm); % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,0) -- (\iAngle:1cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
    %
    \draw[densely dotted,blue] (\iAngle:1cm) -- (\iAngle:1cm |- 0,0); % vertical line
    \draw[densely dotted,red] (\iAngle:1cm) -- (0,0 |- \iAngle:1cm); % horizontal line
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,->,rotate=\iAngle] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    %
    % grid
    \foreach \i in {1, 2, 3 ,4} \draw [dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] ($(\i*pi/2+2.0,-1.5)$)--($(\i*pi/2+2.0,1.5)$);
    \foreach \i in {-1, 1} \draw [dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt] (2,\i)--(8.8,\i);
    %
    %the arc
    \draw [cyan, ultra thick] (1cm,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=\iAngle, radius=1cm];
    \draw[line width=1.pt, cyan] (2,0)--(\fpeval{2+\iAngle*pi/180},0);
    %
    % funciones sen y cos
    \draw[line width=1.pt,smooth,samples=50,domain=2.0:\fpeval{2+\iAngle*pi/180},red] plot (\x,\fpeval{sin(\x-2)});
    \draw[line width=1.pt,smooth,samples=50,domain=2.0:\fpeval{2+\iAngle*pi/180},blue] plot (\x,\fpeval{cos(\x-2)});
    \node[red,blue,right] at (-2,-3.8)
      {\footnotesize$\cos(\,\iAngle^{\mathrm{o}}\,) = \fpeval{round(cosd(\iAngle),4)}$};
    \node[red,red,right] at (-2,-3.4)
      {\footnotesize$\cos(\,\iAngle^{\mathrm{o}}\,) = \fpeval{round(sind(\iAngle),4)}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
%
\end{document}
```